# Can you row count in crystals to choose where to display data?

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport, crystal-reports-2016

Is it possible to use count() in crystals to decide if a sub-report should display data in the original page or on a new page? Basically right now I have report with a sub-report and if the sub report has more than a certain number of rows then I need all of the rows to be on a separate page.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a SQL Expression Field to count the rows that will appear in your sub-report. Then you could use the result of this SQL Expression Field in the evaluation of a formula of the `New Page Before` property of the section that displays your sub-report.  This property is found in the Section Expert, Paging tab if you are not familiar with it.